# Can't locate Core/Utility.pm in @INC

Tags: linux, perl, opensuse

I have a script that contains the directive :

```
use Core::Utility
```

and I am getting the error "Can't locate Core/Utility.pm in @INC". I'm running OpenSUSE 11.4 and have tried :`sudo zypper in -C 'perl(Core::Utility)'` but it doesn't find anything and I can't find any references to it on the web. I don't know any perl, I'm just trying to get a startup script running in /etc/init.d

Comment: no go. I got the script from another system on our network which is running RHL (I don't know the version) and I found the script located in /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/Core/Utility.pm. I'm going to try and just copy it over and see what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no module named `Core::Utility` on CPAN, which strongly suggests that you're dealing with some in-house module that's not been released to the public. So the solution is non-technical: If you want to find out about that module, contact the system administrator of the machine you got the script from, or another person you think might know something about it.

Comment: I ended up talking to the admin and we decided not to use the script. Instead we're using a simplified setup.

Answer (score 1):

In your error, you should also get something like "@INC Contains: ". If /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8 is not in there, you can add it with this line in the script:

```
use lib '/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8';
```

[perldoc -v @INC](http://p3rl.org/var#%40INC)